# magento 2.3 theme installation

Tags: magento2.3

I have installed theme it works fine but later I found that some links on my theme not working ..so I want to know how to install theme on localhost and how to import database of theme on localhost in magento 2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker container for magento. How install see instruction. For example https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento2

Comment: Smolin , please the  question again

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your Magento running locally. The manually way to install Magento theme is comping the theme folder to `<Magento root dir>/app/design/frontend` and make sure your theme folder respects the pattern `<Vendor_Name/<theme_name>`

This information and more about how to install the theme you can find [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-install.html)

Related to the database, you can make a dump from your production environment and restores it on your machine.